# Cant install sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, module

```
Collecting sklearn
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post4.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pcyxpzcb\sklearn_723cb38e743643938d1557fc983aa4b5\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          LONG_DESCRIPTION = f.read()
        File "C:\Python 3710\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 7: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Getting above error...

Any insights on how to solve this?

I used the `pip install sklearn` command in a virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

`scikit-learn` (imported as `sklearn`) is correctly installed with

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Note the entry on the `sklearn` [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/):

> The `sklearn` PyPI package is deprecated use `scikit-learn` instead

Answer (score 0):

Check the Scikit Learn website [Installation Document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)

and you can install scikit-learn by foloowing commands:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

These commands for checking installation:

```
# to see which version and where scikit-learn is installed
python -m pip show scikit-learn

# to see all packages installed in the active virtualenv
python -m pip freeze  

python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"
```